# Recover partially download file auto deleted by Chrome

Tags: linux, google-chrome, filesystems, download, chromium

> Where can I find **partially completed download** file (from chrome )
>   on my system as(chrome and chromium) it delete them in event of
>   interruption (NET ISSUE).
>
> I need the file so that I complete download process using wget
>
> The file weigh 1 GB before getting interrupted(NET ISSUE) I happen to
>   download
>
> 825 MB I dont want to download the 825 MB chunk again
>
> If deleted how can I recover it back .
>
> Thanks

Comment: JFI for those who cant find what i trying to say here a another link that describe the same issue in more detail http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=28612

Answer (score 0):

Assuming chrome didn't actually delete (IE unlink) the file, it should be in `/tmp`, or in the target download directory (probably `~/Downloads/`), just hidden.

If chrome did unlink the file (which that thread makes it sound like)... you're most likely better off restarting the download than trying to recover that.

Comment: that correct chrome actually unlink the file moment it encounter a issue in network. Restarting is definitely an options but I was is there a way to recover that deleted file from system . I'm aware of the tools to recover deleted file(like scapel etc) from system but I had very bad experience of them as i cant a find a way to recover any named file plus they tend to assign a different name  to all deleted irrespective of what was there actual file name is . Could you please provide a under what name the deleted file my chrome is named can help in data recovery tool like scapel

Comment: The problem is the way in which file deletion works (specifically under linux).  When you delete a file, the record is removed, and the space is marked free.  Undelete tools look at the disk, find things "that look like they were files", and let you see them.  Since the file record is gone, you can't tell what the file name was, or whatever... you just have a chunk of data, which the tool guesses was once a file.  Thus, you have to check them over, until you find what you're looking for.